# Making Selenium work with bug reporting software

Tags: python, selenium, bug-tracking, mantis

I've developed an automated test application with Selenium (using Python) and I was wondering if there was a way to automatically generate a bug report in a bug tracker such as Mantis. I have looked on Google but no luck so far.

I want to be able to track the bug (open, resolved, ongoing) once generated and assign it to a person or a team.

Comment: Yep, that's possible. The actual implementation will depend on the bugtracker you're using. Mantis, for example, [exposes a SOAP API](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.html#ADMIN.CONFIG.SOAP) for doing things like reporting issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry if i'm abusing of your kindness but could you provide me with an example? Or some guidance on how to implement it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Carsten answer i was able to find 
http://wiki.opencsw.org/file-bugs-via-a-script
and my implementation is going forward. It seems that mantis is the best tool for my need.